# Should I ask on Literature whether it's true that streets in Ireland in 1955 were "end-on to hills", more often than those in England?

Tags: support, scope, specific-question

Philip Larkin's 1955 poem "The Importance of Elsewhere" implies that Irish streets are often end-on to hills.

This [answer on Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372426/952249) contains the suggestion that the answer to the question [Where on Stack Exchange should I ask whether the streets in Ireland in 1955 were "end-on to hills" more often than those in England?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372424/952249) is either "Literature Stack Exchange" or "History Stack Exchange".

I had a look at Literature Help but did not see anything specifically referring to that type of question.

Should I ask this question on Literature?

Comment: FWIW, the person who answered your question on Meta SE is a moderator of Literature, so they know what they're talking about w.r.t. this site's scope :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this question would be OK for Literature, as long as you ask it from the point of view of investigating the poem. For example, *"Is this description of streets in Larkin's poem accurate?"* You might get answers along the lines of "yes it is [with evidence]" or "no, but Larkin describing streets like this makes poetic sense because [...]". The [historical-context](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-context) tag would be appropriate.

If you wanted to ask it as a purely historical question, *"Were Irish streets in 1955 like this?"*, then History SE would probably be more appropriate (although I don't know their site scope very well).

But if you start from the poem (which is on-topic for Literature) and pose a question about its historical accuracy, that should be fine for us. You might even learn more about Larkin and/or the poem than you expected to.